# Deadlock Prevention(Java+MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, deadlock

i have an sql class that connects to the database and updates the information from my game server. I was wondering if anything here would cause a deadlock and what are good ways to prevent deadlocks. I am new to alot of things so any tips would be great :)

```
package server.util;

import java.sql.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import server.model.players.Client;

public class SQL {

public static Connection con = null;
public static Statement stmt;
public static boolean connectionMade;
public static void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://URL/DATABASE", "USERNAME", "PASS");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);
            return rs;
        } else {
            stmt.executeUpdate(s);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        destroyConnection();
        createConnection();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void destroyConnection() {
    try {
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        connectionMade = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static boolean saveHighScore(Client clientToSave) {
    try {
        query("DELETE FROM `skills` WHERE playerName = '"+clientToSave.playerName+"';");
        query("DELETE FROM `skillsoverall` WHERE playerName = '"+clientToSave.playerName+"';");
        //query("DELETE FROM `scores` WHERE playerName = '"+clientToSave.playerName+"';");
        query("INSERT INTO `skills` (`playerName`,`Attacklvl`,`Attackxp`,`Defencelvl`,`Defencexp`,`Strengthlvl`,`Strengthxp`,`Hitpointslvl`,`Hitpointsxp`,`Rangelvl`,`Rangexp`,`Prayerlvl`,`Prayerxp`,`Magiclvl`,`Magicxp`,`Cookinglvl`,`Cookingxp`,`Woodcuttinglvl`,`Woodcuttingxp`,`Fletchinglvl`,`Fletchingxp`,`Fishinglvl`,`Fishingxp`,`Firemakinglvl`,`Firemakingxp`,`Craftinglvl`,`Craftingxp`,`Smithinglvl`,`Smithingxp`,`Mininglvl`,`Miningxp`,`Herblorelvl`,`Herblorexp`,`Agilitylvl`,`Agilityxp`,`Thievinglvl`,`Thievingxp`,`Slayerlvl`,`Slayerxp`,`Farminglvl`,`Farmingxp`,`Runecraftlvl`,`Runecraftxp`,`Hunterlvl`,`Hunterxp`,`Summonlvl`,`Summonxp`) VALUES ('"+clientToSave.playerName+"',"+clientToSave.playerLevel[0]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[0]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[1]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[1]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[2]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[2]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[3]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[3]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[4]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[4]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[5]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[5]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[6]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[6]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[7]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[7]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[8]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[8]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[9]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[9]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[10]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[10]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[11]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[11]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[12]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[12]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[13]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[13]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[14]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[14]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[15]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[15]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[16]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[16]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[17]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[17]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[18]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[18]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[19]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[19]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[20]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[20]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[21]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[21]+","+clientToSave.playerLevel[22]+","+clientToSave.playerXP[22]+");");
        query("INSERT INTO `skillsoverall` (`playerName`,`lvl`,`xp`) VALUES ('"+clientToSave.playerName+"',"+(clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[0]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[1]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[2]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[3]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[4]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[5]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[6]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[7]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[8]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[9]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[10]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[11]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[12]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[13]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[14]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[15]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[16]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[17]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[18]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[19]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[20]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[21]) + clientToSave.getLevelForXP(clientToSave.playerXP[22]))+","+((clientToSave.playerXP[0]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[1]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[2]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[3]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[4]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[5]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[6]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[7]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[8]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[9]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[10]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[11]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[12]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[13]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[14]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[15]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[16]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[17]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[18]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[19]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[20]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[21]) + (clientToSave.playerXP[22]))+");");
        //query("INSERT INTO `scores` (`playerName`,`killcount`,`pkpoints`,`pcpoints`) VALUES ('"+clientToSave.playerName+"',"+clientToSave.KC+","+clientToSave.pkPoints+","+clientToSave.pcPoints+");");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Why is it static? Is there a good reason for that? You really should use static things if you don't have to remember the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to worry about synchronization on the Java side, because java.sql implementations are not thread safe.  And you need to think about isolation on the database server, balancing responsiveness with ACID.

I'd recommend a few other things for your Java class:

1. Use a connection pool.  Destroying and creating connections is very expensive.  Your SQL class should not be handling such chores.
2. Use PreparedStatement and bind variables.  Creating a query string that way is a bad idea.
3. Close resources in a finally block.

All those static strings...I'm reading this on a mobile phone, but what I'm seeing is not good.  You may have a serious violation of 1st normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks are generally cause by poorly synchronized code.  The most typical case is that Thread A grabs a lock on resource X, Thread B grabs a lock on resource Y, and then both threads wait while they each try to grab the resource they don't yet have locked.

Since your code has no synchronization at all, it should be fine.

To avoid deadlock problems, try to do the minimum amount of work possible inside of synchronized blocks.  Be very careful about calling code external to the class inside a synchronized block, as this external code may try to obtain a lock and produce a deadlock.  Remember that doing a database query is a call to external code, and it is not unusual for a db query to lock on resources inside the database.

Are you actually seeing deadlocks, or are you just being cautious?

Comment: Many people that use mysql in their servers to save info to database have deadlocks, I was wondering if the mysql was causing it. Like, let's say they make their mysql connection upon user's login, and if two users log on at the same time, will that give  any problems?

Comment: I don't know enough about the causes of deadlocks within databases to answer intelligently.  Hopefully somebody else can jump in and help you there. Good luck.